# Получить диапазон из массива в vb6

Tags: visual-basic, vb6

Дан массив целых положительных чисел. Допустим: array(0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12).

Нужна функция, которая отсортирует массив так, чтобы на выходе получилась такая строчка: 0,1,3,5-9,12

````
Dim arr(5) As String, a(5) As String
arr(0) = 1
arr(1) = 3
arr(2) = 4
arr(3) = 5
arr(4) = 7

For i = 0 To 4
If Not arr(i) = vbNullString Then
    Do Until Not UBound(arr)
        a(i) = arr(i)
    Loop
    If arr(i) = Val(a(UBound(a))) + 1 Then
        a(i) = arr(i)
    End If
End If

If UBound(a) < 3 Then
    result = "," & a(i) & ","
Else
    result = a(0) & "-" & a(UBound(a)) & ","
End If

Do Until Not UBound(arr)
    a(i) = arr(i)
Loop

Next i

result = Replace(result, ",", "")

MsgBox result```
````

Comment: И с чем возникли проблемы?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, как лучше сравнивать элементы массива. Добавил код, который имеется на данный момент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот код

```
Dim arr = New Integer() {0, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12}

result = arr(0)

Function addDelim(str, delim)
  If Right(str, 1) <> "-" Then
    addDelim = str & delim
  Else
    addDelim = str
  End If
End Function

For i = 1 To UBound(arr) - 1
  If arr(i) = arr(i - 1) + 1 And arr(i) + 1 = arr(i + 1) Then
    result = addDelim(result, "-")
  Else
    result = addDelim(result, ",")
    result = result & arr(i)
  End If
Next i

If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
  result = addDelim(result, ",")
  result = result & arr(UBound(arr))
End If

MsgBox result
```

он исходит из того, что исходный массив отсортирован и он не пустой

Comment: Спасибо, чуть чуть отредактировал. Все работает

Comment: @kolya00736 в ответе ошибки были? Я тестировал на VBS. Если да, то отредактируйте мой ответ или напишите в комментариях